# Load/Reload Google Places Autocomplete input value from the place_id

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I have an Angular application that uses Google Places Autocomplete. I use it to help people find contact addresses easily, like this

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

After an user submits an address as a contact address, it is saved in a SQL database **including** its place id (Google's place id).

Now after the user refreshes the webpage, I would like to pre-fill the Places autocomplete input from the place id stored in the database. Google's documentation is super confusing and I am unsure of what is the correct way to achieve this, it shouldn't be a hard thing to do. I am expecting something like

```
var autocomplete = google.maps.places.Autocomplete.initFromPlaceId(_inputRef: HTMLInputElement, _placeId: string)
```

But I fail to find an easy solution. Anything harder, seems like overthinking it. Maybe somebody with some industry expertise can help me out.

Thanks

**#Edit 1**

I found a way to retrieve the place by its ID, like this

```
let placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService( this.xxx.nativeElement );
placesService.getDetails({placeId: 'xxxxxxxxxxx-Wo'}, function( _result, _status) {
    console.log( _result, _status );
});
```

But still no dice on how to re-initialise the actual places autocomplete field with this value.

**#Edit 2**

I am currently just setting the HTML value of the autocomplete container  to be the address string of the loaded address. Still looking for the correct solution to load an unique ID into that HTML input, but this midway solution seems to work also. It's just that it might not always be 1v1 to what was searched before, if google changes their results or result order.